# how to adjust jspanel(jquery panel) size in jquery and asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

We are using jspanels in our project as tool bar and whenever we click toolicons,jspanels will come as a popup and will display controls like textboxes for inputting data and gridview for displaying data.In normal way whenever we enter data in `textboxes`,after saving data it will be displayed in gridview.Jspanel will be adjusted to accommodate `gridview`.Now the problem i am facing is, i am minimizing jspanel by using `jspanel.minimize()` for certain times after that i will use `jspanel.normalize()` in order to move to the previous position.After that when ever i display results in `gridview` jspanel is not adjusting its size rather `gridview` is going inside jspanel, and i have to drag the corner of jspanel in order to display `gridview`.How can i avoid this issue rather dragging the panel.Here is the code i used for jspanel

```
var jteamNetworkPanel = null;
    function searchByPanel() {
        document.getElementById("divtDetails").style.visibility = "";
        var content = document.getElementById("divtDetails").outerHTML;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jteamNetworkPanel = $.jsPanel({
                draggable: {
                    containment: "#tDiv"
                },
                selector: '#tDiv',
                content: content,
                size: { width: 'auto', height: 'auto' },
                title: "Test",
                position: { top: 50, left: "center" },
                theme: 'warning'
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile jsPanel version 3 is released and I would suggest switching to version 3 for at least two reasons concerning your issue:

- minimize() works different and has no more negative side effects I
  know of
- using "auto" with panel size is also improved and works a lot better

But v3 doesn't work with browsers older than IE11 and you need to check the docs since some options and methods are renamed.

http://jspanel.de/